# How to use Oauth2 for user authentication in gRPC

Tags: authentication, go, oauth-2.0, grpc

(I am pretty new in grpc and golang)

I have a website that uses [grpc-web](https://github.com/improbable-eng/grpc-web) package to communicate to a banckend grpc api server in golang. I need user authentication with github. But I am having difficulties in understanding how to use oauth2 token based authentication in grpc. I will appreciate if you can share your idea.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the way to use OAuth2 with grpc-web is to add the header to the metadata object which is the second argument to each rpc call.

```
my_grpc_web_client.MyMethod(myRequestProto, {Authorization: "Bearer <token>"});
```

References: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/351 , specifically https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/351#issuecomment-436050409